# How to use $(window).delegate('selector','resize',function handler) when selector is into an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use as a selector an element from DOM inside an iFrame.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery/javascript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access anything in an iframe with JavaScript running outside this frame.

Browsers has a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to prevent security problems like [phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing)

(If you host the content of this iframe your self you may have a look at [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load HTML chunks into your page)

Comment: The iframe has been dinamically created from my code, therefore I have full access to its elements.

Comment: ok, maybe you should try to load it with jQuery load(), then the html is injected into your page instead if iframe

Comment: The contents of the iframe is not the problem because it's added dinamically as well. I'd like to use delegate using an element into an iframe as a selector, but i don't know the syntax of the selector for this case.